# When is cancel url accessed in express checkout paypal api?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I noticed you specify cancel url in api when doing express check out but when is that url accessed? I don't see "cancel" transaction or anything in sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you cannot see that? It is there in the sandbox site 
On left you have order summary, and on right you have

> order         |  1.Have a paypal account 
>   summary   |  2. Create a paypal account

below that you should see a link called "**Cancel and return to [your-merchant name]**"
That is where the cancel url is used. If user wants to cancel the order. If you cannot see that try it in yours, try any other 3rd party demo site's express checkout like shopify demo stores, you will see that.

Answer (score 0):

> Specify the cancel URL. The cancel URL is the page to which PayPal
>   redirects your buyer’s browser if the buyer does not approve the
>   payment. Typically, this is the secure page `(https://...)` on your site
>   from which you redirected the buyer to PayPal.
>
> Note: You can pass SetExpressCheckout request values as parameters in
>   your URL to have the values available, if necessary, after PayPal
>   redirects to your URL.

```
CANCELURL=cancel_url
```